# How to calcluate sum of column python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am simply trying to get the sum of a column ('Value') in a dataframe in python. I believe I am creating the dataframe, but I am not sure. I am getting a result back, however, it's not the result I imagine when it comes to .sum().

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open('new_taste.csv', 'r') as csv_trades:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_trades)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=csv_reader)
    total = df['Value'].sum()
    df.loc['Value'] = pd.Series(df['Value'].sum(), index=['Value'])
    print(df['Value'])
```

is giving me

```
0                                                      133
1                                                      180
2                                                     -117
3                                                     -159
4                                                        1
                               ...                        
316                                                     14
317                                                     14
318                                                     19
319                                                     18
Value    133180-117-15911-84-3-10-23434245-23-3085-5241...
Name: Value, Length: 321, dtype: object
```

I noticed it's bringing back every number, not the sum of the numbers. I would like to bring back the sum.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? It’s like 10 lines of code. In any case, look at the last line of the output you shared, there’s a pretty big hint at what the issue is.

Comment: Also, Pandas can read CSV files, and you probably don’t need to make that Series. You create a variable `total` to hold the sum, but then recalculate it anyway.

Comment: The series was to see why I was getting a very long string of numbers and it occurred to me that I was see the numbers in Value all together. At first, I didn't know if it was grabbing from the other columns which you don't see. This allowed me to ask a more succinct question to see what I was missing, and it was a very simple thing: float. I don't have the best debugging habits.

Comment: _The series was to see why I was getting....in Value all together._ Sorry, I’m not sure I understand what you mean. Can you put it differently, maybe?

Comment: When I print just the total function it only came back with just one line. Since I have a bunch of other columns that you don't see in my example, I wasn't sure if I was grabbing from the right column, as I'm still very much learning. So, I brought in the series and simply explained how I arrived where I was. This is my debugging method and it's why you see two lines of code doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems return string values after recognizing df['Value'] values to string.

How about change 9th line of your code to below

> `df.loc['Value'] = pd.Series(df['Value'].sum(), index=['Value'])`

And could you share what it returns to "total" variable.

Comment: Thanks for throwing out the string values thing. I was able to find the fix based on what you said, even though the code snippet you provided was the same as what I had originally posted.

Comment: Anyway glad to help you haha

Answer (score 0):

I think this is my answer. I have to go through and check the math cause I believe I have to further tweak what I'm adding up. I was returning a string.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open('new_taste.csv', 'r') as csv_trades:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_trades)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=csv_reader)
    total = df['Value'].sum()
    df.loc['Value'] = pd.Series(df['Value'].astype(float).sum(), index=['Value'])
    print(df['Value'])

print(total)
```

Comment: Read the CSV file using Pandas, you can specify the data type there if it fails to infer it properly. You know that you’re creating a row to store the sum, right? That doesn’t seem ideal.

Comment: I've only been looking into csv and pandas the last few days, not having looked at python for about a year now.